# Error: "No memory left on the GPU even for a minimal block"

Tags: vtk

I am using VTKSmartVolumeWrapper to do some volume rendering and have been running on a computer with an ATI GPU and it has been running fine.

I am running an AMD (ATI) FirePro M8900 (FireGL) Mobility Pro Graphics

A new person coming on the project just started and has a new Dell laptop with an NVidia Quadro Pro in it, and running my software, he gets the following error:

I've checked and the computer seems to be running the latest drivers from Dell (311.44)

The version of VTK I am running is from Activiz 5.8.0 (I'm running from a C#.net client), which is the latest version.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a simple suggestion (nothing more than that, really!): It seems that the error is raised from [vtkOpenGLGPUVolumeRayCastMapper.h](http://docs.mitk.org/0.99.3/vtkMitkOpenGLGPUVolumeRayCastMapper_8cpp_source.html) (see line 5840). Maybe, looking at the code, you could get an idea of it.
However, this [link](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/vtkOpenGLGPUVolumeRayCastMapper-on-a-specific-GPU-td4437454.html) seems to speaking about it (even if I'm not sure about it...).

Comment: There is also a [vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper.h](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper.html) (no OpenGL in the name), you could looking at it too (again, it's just a suggestion).

BTW, did you mean "NVidia *Quadro* Pro"?

Comment: Yes, I meant Quadro Pro (got my NVidia's confused with my Audi's). I'm not a GPU guy, so my attempts to read vtkOpenGLGPUVolumeRayCastMapper haven't been fruitful so far. It appears that I'm getting the error because it is failing to load a texture into the GPU...I'm not setting any textures for my mapper.

Comment: I see the answer of yours...Unfortunately, I can't be of any other help, but I'm glad that you've founded the error's cause...
You have raised a nice issue, though...Hope that you'll find a definitive fix for that.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I finally figured out what was going on...

The computer with the NVidia card had 4GB of GPU memory. By default the mapper uses 75% of the available GPU memory.

Unfortunately, it appears that the max memory is stored as a "signed int", (I'm not sure if this was in the C# wrapper or in the C++ based code), so it was being set to an unsigned value of 3GB, which is represented as -1GB as a signed int.

So, as a temporary measure, I set my max memory to 1.9 GB, and now everything works as long as the GPU has at least 1.9 GB of memory (I will need to put a check in for that).

I will report this as an issue to the VTK folks...thanks for the help